# MFP8 - Delete Deployed Adapter from DB

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, adapter

In MFP 8, How do i delete the deployed ADAPTERS from DB instead of MFP Console.

During development, we have deployed many adapters, Deleting one by one from MFP console is time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MFP 8.0, an artifact deployment ( application registration or adapter) involves more than one table. As such, a deletion directly from the MFP administration database is error prone and can cause issues , if not done correctly.

To prevent such issues, you should either delete the adapter directly from console or via REST API. However, you can only do so, one at a time.